# Special kind of Server Side Include of Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have to create a new asp.net mvc page that integrates content provided by a cms on the server side static. my mvc page provides a masterpage with the navigation and certain links should point to pages of the cms (which is installed on the same server). it should be something like a "server side iframe".

my idea is to create a controller which loads the page of the cms using a webrequest, extracts the body part of the page and passes the extracted data to the view. the view simply outputs the passed html. i also plan to add some logic to pass post requests to the cms (for news letter subscriptions, contact forms, ...)

now my question is: is it possible to implement this solution? or is there a better way to do this on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/applicationrequestrouting) to just hand off requests to your CMS, or do you need to include the externally provided content within an existing masterpage?

If you need to use the masterpage I would stick to the solution you suggest, although I might investigate the most robust and efficient option for querying the content from the CMS and perhaps if caching would be a good option.

Comment: I have to check, if Application Request Routing could solve my problem. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: All pages should share the same header (which contains navigation and login logic handled by my page) and footer. So i thought creating a masterpage is the easiest solution...

Answer (score 0):

It is undoubtedly possible, but keeping track of users, authentication, cookies etc. seems like a really tedious job. Also, embedding css classes, hard-coded styling etc. from the CMS in your MVC site could give you a severe headache.

If the CMS isn't home-brewed it probably has an API. In that case I would much prefer to use the API to get at the data I needed and then render that data using pure MVC. This will give you a much cleaner and more stable integration with the CMS.

Comment: Unfortunly the cms doesn't provide an api.